# Responsive flipbook with for all mobile/web/iPad

Tags: jquery

I need jquery responsive flip book effect.
It should 2 page flip on iPad/web and for mobile it should be single page flip effect (like image slide show with flip effect)

I did Google for this, there're many responsive plugins but nothing match my requirement,
Please suggest me some best fit.

Answer (score 0):

I may be biassed but I would recommend having a look at our (FlexPaper) components - there are both open source and commercial options you can choose from. You can find them all here:

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/